# How do I make a more succint, stratified table on R?

Tags: r, statistics

I currently have a table of proportions for my project. My proportions are specified by class and region that people live in for the output. Example in the table below.

| Class | Region | Prop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.95 |
| 0 | 2 | 0.32 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.63 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.34 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.87 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.95 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.88 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.95 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.1515 |

I have dummy values in place for the class levels and the regions. The prop column is associated with the proportion of the outcome of interest. So for example, in region 1, those in the lowest class (0) have a prevalence of the outcome interest at 95%. How can I better organize this when I want to output a table into my paper. Apologies in advance if this is a simple answer, still trying to grasp R

Comment: Do you want to show the Prop in %?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack overflow. For future questions in R, please use `dput(df)` to output a sample of your data for us to work on.

Your table is in tidy format as is, and this is great for calculations/r-functions and what not. But for humans it is not so good. This question leads to opinionated answers, so here is my opinion: You should widen your table so that each column is a region (1, 2 or 3) and each row is a Class (0, 1, 2, 3) and then each cell value is the Prop value: In R this can be done like this using the package `tidyr`:

```
require(tidyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  Class = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  Region = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3),
  Prop = rnorm(9)+1
)

#Takes each unique value of Region and makes a column out of it
readable <- tidyr::pivot_wider(
  data = df,
  names_from = Region,
  values_from = Prop
)

#Change the names to something more human readable
names(readable) <- c("Class", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3")

#Output:
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Class `Region 1` `Region 2` `Region 3`
  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     0      0.374      1.18       NA   
2     1      0.164      2.60       NA   
3     2      1.33       0.180       1.49
4     3     NA          1.74        1.58
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will use dput in the future. This is super helpful, but is there an efficient way of combining the class levels and the regions without manually inputting their values?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by combining class levels and regions. If you mean to paste/stitch/concatenate the class values with the regions you can do something similar to `class_region <- paste(df$Class, df$Region, sep = "_")`